# Breaking up large arrays into smaller ones in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

I have a double array of image pixels whose size is dependent on the image size. Let's say the image is 1000x1334, I'll be having a carryOutput[1000][1334] double array.

I need to break up the array into smaller double [9][9] array under the following conditions. I have a created a for loop for it but got stuck half way.

```
//smaller array z    
double[][] z = new double[9][9];

     for(int length = 0; length < carryOutput.length; length+=8)
     {
         for(int width = 0; width < carryOutput[0].length; width+=8)
         {
             ... code to fill in z array here ....
         }
     }
```

Basically, I want to have multiple smaller arrays that are subarrays of carryOutput based on the conditions in the for loop.

```
EG: length = 0, width = 0 --> z[0][0] until z[8][8] = carryOutput[0][0] until carryOutput [8][8]
    length = 0, width = 8 --> z[0][0] until z[8][8] = carryOutput[0][9] until carryOutput [8][17]
    ....
```

The problem here is there a way that I can avoid breaking into many arrays. You see, if it's a 1000x1000 image, there would be around 100+ smaller arrays.

I have a running MATLAB code which actually does this job. I'm trying to translate it to JAVA.

Attached is the portion of the MATLAB code:

```
      e = size(carryOutput);
        for length=1:8:e(1)-8;
            for wide=1:8:e(2)-8;

                z=coef(length:length+8,wide:wide+8);
        ...

    row = 1;
    col = 2;   

            if (z(row,col) < z(row,col+1))
                    smaller = smaller+1;  
                if z(row,col+2) > z(row,col+1)
                smaller_plus = smaller_plus+1;
                else if z(row,col+2) < z(row,col+1)
                smaller_minus = smaller_minus +1;
                else if z(row,col+2) == z(row,col+1)
                smaller_static = smaller_static +1;
                end;end;end;

....
```

The reason I want an output something similar to MATLAB because, I'd have to compare the rows and columns of each smaller array later in the code. To write a code to compare for 100 different arrays would be troublesome.

Can anyone highlight how should my code be to solve this problem.

Comment: ..."*created a for loop for it but got stuck*"..."*I want to have multiple smaller arrays that are subarrays of carryOutput*"..."*is there a way that I can avoid breaking into many arrays*"..."*running MATLAB code...trying to translate it to JAVA*" It's hard to tell what you are exactly asking.

Answer (score 0):

How did your app get stuck?  If array sizes are very large it's likely in garbage collection.  I wouldn't be concerned with splitting the array.  Rather, I'd recommend adding heap to the java runtime:

```
java -Xms1g -Xmx1g ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't avoid having to create the 100+ smaller arrays but there are optimizations that could make your code run much faster. For example, you can use the System.arrayCopy() method instead of the inner for loop to move data faster.

You also mentioned that the purpose of these smaller arrays is to be compared with each other, so a huge optimization that you can do is to store some hashed information about their contents (e.g. the CRC32 of the 9x9 bytes) and use these hashed values to figure out whether two 9x9 arrays are different without having to iterate through the 81 bytes.